# Mod_rewrite with optional GET values

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

Okay, I have this `Mod_Rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([iI][tT]/|[eE][nN]/)?([a-zA-Z\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

which listen to just two GET variables. The problem is some pages have three or four GET variables and I would like to pass them as normal GETs (for instance `www.mysite.com/en/page/?id=0`).

Right now if I access `www.mysite.com/en/page/?id=0` it discards the id.

However, if I use

```
^([iI][tT]/|[eE][nN]/)?([a-zA-Z\-]+)/\?(.+)?$ index.php?page=$2&lang=$1&$3 [L]
```

it won't work at all.

Clearly I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `[QSA]` flag (see [Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html))